# my mysql query is resulting in 1 for number of rows regardless if value is there or not

Tags: php, mysql

here is my mysql statement:

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(*) from usersecurity where 
     email='".$_SESSION['username']."'"); 
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Problem is, from my understanding, its always returning the value 1, even if the username doesn't exist in the table...why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` with return a row with a single value containing zero.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(*)` will always return a row, even if the result  is zero.  You need to examine the result of that column:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM t1 WHERE email = "SOME NON EXISTENT EMAIL";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['count']; // 0
```

An alternative would be to select the count as the number of rows:

```
SELECT TRUE FROM t1 WHERE email = "SOME NON EXISTENT EMAIL";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_num_rows($result); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A COUNT(*) query always returns a single row. If you want the $ of rows then do one of the following.

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(*) as ROWS from usersecurity where 
 email='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $rows['ROWS'];
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("select * as ROWS from usersecurity where 
     email='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always get one row from the result query. That value will some value greater than or equal to zero. You need to inspect the actual count returned not the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT query is returning the following:

```
select count(*)...
----------------------
0
```

Thus, `mysql_num_rows($result)` is appropriately returning 1 as a result. If you're looking to get the value of your count, then you need to take an approach like the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("select count(*) from usersecurity where 
     email='".$_SESSION['username']."'"); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row[0];
```